# Creating url with parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I am trying to create an url for product filtering.
The url I need is www.example.com/category/?brand=apple|windows

If the parameter (brand) exists, add the given value with separator |.
If the value already exists, do nothing.

Also with multiple parameters that can find if it needs to add the ? or &.

I tried several tutorials, but I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild all requests.

```js
var filters = {
    brand : ['apple', 'windows'],
    color: ['black', 'white']
};


var getFilterURL = function(_filters){
  var keys = Object.keys(_filters);
  var loc = location.pathname;
  var params = "";
  
  for(var i =0; i < keys.length; i++){
   if(_filters[keys[i]].length > 0){
    params += "&" + keys[i] + "=" + _filters[keys[i]].join('|')  
    }
  }
  
  if(params != ""){
    loc += "?" + params.substring(1);
  }
  
  return loc;
}


console.log(getFilterURL(filters));
```

Comment: What if there are the same variables in the array, how to filter the duplicate?